# ActiveMQ - java.io.EOFException

Tags: activemq-classic

There appear to be a few posts relating to a java.io.EOFException WARN message that intermittently appears (reproduced below) but none that provide details on how to fix the issue. Firstly I assume that as it is a WARN message that it should not be ignored? Otherwise an INFO or DEBUG message would be output?

I have a simple consumer/publisher on my workstation and have ActiveMQ running on 2 VMs (Tried both 5.10.0 and 5.14.1)

The transport connector for each VM is:

```
    <transportConnector name="openwire" 
uri="tcp://<IPAddress2>:61616?maximumConnections=1000&
amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

Network connectors:

```
<networkConnector name="<host1>"
    uri="static:(tcp://<IPAddress1>:61616)"
    networkTTL="3"/>
```

On my consumer/publisher I have the broker-url:

```
failover:(tcp://<IPAddress1>:61616,tcp://<IPAddress2>:61616)?randomize=false
```

so that I have a master/slave deployment.

Any ideas what I may have wrong?

> WARN [publisher] FailoverTransport (FailoverTransport.java:260) -
>   Transport (tcp:///:61616@46603) failed, reason:  ,
>   attempting to automatically reconnect java.io.EOFException    at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)     at
>   org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)